# Error: Error: Unsupported provider: undefined in electron js

Tags: electron, electron-updater

I have developed a electron js app with angular .I want to have electron-updater.But its giving me above error .
this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Gamer",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "main.js", 
  "dependencies": { ...},
  "devDependencies": { 
   "electron-builder": "^22.1.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.0",
     "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "build": "ng build",   
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder -mwl",
    "release": "build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.Gamer",
    "files": [
      "*.js",
      "build",
      "dist"
    ],
    "mac": {
      "target": "zip"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "squirrel",
      "icon":"src/app/assets/images/app-icon.png"
    }

  }
}
```

dev-update.yml

```
appId: com.electron.Gamer
publish:
    provider: github
    token: ab***e
    repo: https://github.com/abc/gamer
    owner: xuz
```

I don't know whether I'm following correct step or not. I tried Provider:generic but thrown above error